# How to add an object to an existing list using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, list, reflection

Using EntityFrameworkCore to connect to a database, After creating models of all tables and a DbContext, I create a new object of this Context with name myContext which has a property (with name of listName) of type List.
I want to create a new object and add it to the list.
Everything works fine but the last line of code:

```cs
myList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(myList, new[] {myObj});
```

which throw an exception of type **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException**

here is the whole code:

```cs
private void AddNewObjectToThisList(string listName) {
var myList = myContext.GetType().GetProperty(listName).GetValue(myContext);
var objType = myList.GetType().GetGeneric Arguments().Single();
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
myList.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(myList, new[] {myObj});
}
```

Comment: the exception from which line ? myList is null ?

Comment: Can you share the exception message?

Comment: Exception is: Inner Exception, InvalidOperationException: Unable to track instance of type 'the list type' because it doesn't have a primary key

Comment: Is this related to Entity Framework?

Comment: actually the myList is of type DbSet<> (using entity framework core to communicate with a database)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show exact types of each object.  "myList is of type DbSet<>" and "a property ... of type List." together is very confusing as presumably both refer to `myList` object...

Comment: Then, do you have an idea about this missing primary key?

Comment: The table has not any primary key. I add it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to be sure about the the code to be right. And It was.
The problem is inserting a new record to the table (myList). myList should have a primary key. After assigning a key the problem was solved.